# How do you upload a file to an ftp server via an ftp proxy using curl, wget etc... . How do we replicate the same using python

Tags: python, curl, ftp

I have to upload files to ftp server via ftp proxy. Heard that curl doesnt have specific support for ftp proxy but it can be done via setting -u string. Can someone help me in this ?